# Attaching String to Variables in a Loop Python

Tags: python-2.7

So I am using python's numpy and I am trying to generate a list 50 random generated variables, each a 100 long.

```
import numpy as np
randn = np.random.randn
var1 = Series(randn(100))
```

Trying to do two things:

1st) Trying to create the 100 variables in a loop. Attaching the index of each number to the string "var", so var1, var2, var3
How do you combine a string and the index variable in a loop?

2) Bind them together into a large matrix/dataframe.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you dynamically create variables in Python via a while loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-a-while-loop)

Comment: Looked through the link couldn't find the answer

Comment: don't skim, read. clue: globals